# Lost connection after simple query for a big table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, timeout

I am running a complex LEFT JOIN query of two tables.

```
Table A - 1.6 million rows
Table B - 700k rows.
```

All columns are indexed.

I tried different debuggings but had no success on finding the problem since I guess that's not too many data.

Anyway I found out that there is no problem if I remove the 'WHERE' clause in my query
But when I try this simple query on table A - it returns "Lost connection".

```
SELECT id FROM table_A ORDER BY id LIMIT 10
```

1. What is the best practice to run this query? I don't wish to exceed the timeout.
2. Are my tables too big and should I "empty" the old data or something?
3. How do you handle big tables with millions of rows and JOINS? All I know that can help is indexing, and I've already done that.

Comment: Why are you using the php tag?

Comment: Beacuse I am using php to run these queries and It might help with the answers

Comment: *complex LEFT JOIN query of two tables. ... All columns are indexed.* Show real DDLs for both tables, real query text and its EXPLAIN. *Are my tables too big* No. This size is average. *It might help with the answers* It either does not affect or interfere with.

Comment: the EXPLAIN also returns lost connection

Comment: increase the timeouts like wait_timeout = 28800
interactive_timeout = 28800 and see if it helps. second check the mysql logs

Comment: when you run your query directly from the database, how long does it take? How many rows does it recover? Sometimes one or several of your filters eliminate most of the data to recover. Use temporary tables if needed.

Comment: But I don't want to make it longer to run the query, I want to it to be efficient.
So all queries with tables with millions of rows should take about 15 seconds?

Comment: 15 seconds is not sufficient time for a time-out. The default limit is 30 seconds.

Comment: sorry I didn't notice it was 30 seconds

Comment: Dup of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/258293/lost-connection-after-simple-query-for-a-big-table

Answer (score 1):

A million rows -- not a problem; a billion rows -- then it gets interesting.  Your tables are not "too big".

"All columns are indexed." -- Usually a mistake.  We need to see the actual query before commenting on what index(es) would be useful.

Possibly you need a "composite" index.

`SELECT id FROM table_A ORDER BY id LIMIT 10` -- If there is an index *starting* with `id`, that will return nearly instantly.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_A` so we can see the schema.